# Breaking out of infinite loop which contains async operations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to make multiple get calls. The only parameter that changes in the url is a number at end. So basically I need some kind of looping and keep triggering the get calls. The get call, once completed will trigger a callback. The callback will check the response for a specific text. If it matches a certain string, I need to break the loop and thus end my program. From what I understand, the loop would keep running and not wait for any async code to complete and call the callback.

In short I need to check for the presence of a certain string in the get call responses. I need to stop making the calls as soon as I find my string in any of the response.

I am fairly new to javascript and nodeJS. Any help would be great.

```
/* Simple Hello World in Node.js */
var https = require('https');
var url="https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=";

var notFound = true;
var page=1;
var code='AF';
while(notFound){
    console.log(page);
    triggerReq(url+page);
    page++;
}

function triggerReq(url){
    //console.log(url);
    https.get(url, (res)=>{
        console.log('callback for - '+url);
        f1(res);
    }       
    );
    /*
    This code currently works because of this end condition for the loop.
    */
    if (page==5){
        notFound=false;
        //console.log('page = '+page);
    }
}

function f1(res){
    console.log('inn');

    res.on('data',(text)=>{
        //console.log('inn');
        var obj = JSON.parse(text);
        for(var x in obj.data){
            console.log(obj.data[x].name);
            if(obj.data[x].alpha2Code==code){
                console.log('### FOUND ### - '+obj.data[x].name);
                notFound=false;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It would be useful to include code in your question

Comment: With the way you've set it up, it's going to fire off a _lot_ of requests, likely before it even gets the first response back. If you really don't want to process the request serially, then you should, at a minimum, probably throttle your requests so that you only send, say, one request per second (adjust as appropriate) and you should check `notFound` in your callback so you can exit that function without bothering to look at the data. But, you may still find problems if more than one page might contain what you are looking for as you won't be guaranteed which page will return first.

Comment: Another alternative would be to send requests in batches. Like, maybe, 5 at a time. And fire off new requests as they come back (assuming you haven't already found what you are looking for).

Comment: Because the async calls are non-blocking and node.js only processes results when the event loop get cycles, you can't code it this way.  This will just run the infinite loop forever starting `https.get()` operations one after another until you run out of resources (sockets or memory) because you never allow any cycles for the event loop to run to process any of the requests.  You can't program this way in an event driven environment like node.js.  Instead, you need to fire ONE request and in its completion event handler, decide if you are done or need to fire another request.